# np.where to create missing value wih a string

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, where-clause

I'm creating a new variable, my aim is to obtain a missing value in "my_var" if the conditions are not true, but instead it creates in "my_var " the value "NaN", as shown by "df.my_var.isnull().any()", which returns False

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
    'age': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73], 
    'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
    'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'age', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])

df['my_var'] = np.where((df['age']>=36) & (df['age']<=42), 'yes',np.where((df['age']>=52) & (df['age']<=73),'no',np.NaN))

df.my_var.isnull().any()
```

the expected output is:

```
data2 = {'my_var': ['yes', 'no', 'yes', np.NaN, 'no']}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['my_var'])
df2
```

Comment: can you edit with expected output ?

Comment: Because of using 'yes' and 'no' strings the datatype of `my_var` is object. So `np.NaN`  became string in the column showing no null values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `numpy.select` instead of nested `numpy.where`:

```
conditions = [df['age'].between(36, 42), df['age'].between(52, 73)]
values = ['yes', 'no']

df['my_var'] = np.select(conditions, values, None)

print(df)

    name  age  preTestScore  postTestScore my_var
0  Jason   42             4             25    yes
1  Molly   52            24             94     no
2   Tina   36            31             57    yes
3   Jake   24             2             62   None
4    Amy   73             3             70     no
```

It's not clear what you require from your final condition:

```
print(df['my_var'].isnull().any())

True
```

If you are checking for Boolean `True`, rather than "Truthy" values, I strongly suggest you use `True` / `False` instead of `"yes"` / `"no"`.

Answer (score 2):

As your `my_var` column is not numeric just replace `np.nan` with `None`

```
df['my_var'] = np.where((df['age']>=36) & (df['age']<=42), 'yes',
              np.where((df['age']>=52) & (df['age']<=73),'no',None))

df.my_var.isnull().any()
```

output:

```
True
```